# how to remove brackets in a particular multiple fields in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I need to remove the brackets '{' from a specific fields (2nd, 4th, 5th , 7th  fields) in a line, I have tried with below command but not helpful

### Data in file

```
a,{1},hello{hi}hello,{+2A},{3},un{i}x,{4}
```

### Desired output

```
a,1,hello{hi}hello,+2A,3,un{i}x,4
```

### Tried unix command

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," 'BEGIN { split("2,4,5,7", F); } { for(N in F) sub("\\(\\)","", $(F[N])) }1' testfile | sed 's/,,/,/g'
```

Comment: problem is in regular expression `"\\(\\)"` will not match `{`, also using gsub will replace all matches

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `awk`:

```
s='a,{1},hello{hi}hello,{2},{3},un{i}x,{4}'

awk -v k='2,4,5,7' 'function strip(n){gsub(/[{}]/, "", $n)}
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; n=split(k, a, /,/)}{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) strip(a[i])} 1' <<< "$s"
```

**Output:**

```
a,1,hello{hi}hello,+2 A,3,un{i}x,4
```

Comment: Not exactly, there can be text in those fields,  I need to remove based on those field positions.

Comment: Hmm you just changed the question after I posted this :) anyway I will edit.

Comment: yeah!! I thought I gave a wrong impression on that example! :)

Comment: @anubhava, `awk: cmd. line:2: BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; n=split(k, a, /,/)} for (i=1; i<=n; i++) strip(a[i])} 1
awk: cmd. line:2:                                                                       ^ syntax error` - You've missed something. I wonder if anyone who upvoted did even test it

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: It was a simple typo, anyone wanting to use this `Awk` should be capable enough to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i~/^(2|4|5|7)$/) gsub(/[}{]/,"",$i) }1' OFS=',' file
```

- `i~/^(2|4|5|7)$/` - if field number matches any item from alternation group

The output:

```
a,1,hello{hi}hello,+2A,3,un{i}x,4
```

Comment: Only caveat is if there are 50 fields then loop will run 50 times for each record even if we are modifying only 4 of them.

Comment: @anubhava, I doubt that your approach will go faster and I'm ready for benchmark.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: It does vary, a loop til `NF` vs a loop until the max occurrences will certainly make a difference

Answer (score 1):

try following too once.

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if((i==2||i==5||i==4||i==7) && (($i ~ /\}/) ||($i ~ /\{/))){gsub(/{|}/,"",$i);}}} 1' OFS=,   Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution here too.

```
awk -F, '{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
  if((i==2||i==5||i==4||i==7) && (($i ~ /\}/) ||($i ~ /\{/))){
    gsub(/{|}/,"",$i)
}}}
1
' OFS=,   Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** If you want to remove ) also considering in same field numbers only, yo could do small editing in above code.

```
awk -F, '{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
  if((i==2||i==5||i==4||i==7) && (($i ~ /\}/) ||($i ~ /\{/))){
    gsub(/{|}|)/,"",$i)
}}}
1
' OFS=,   Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks!! What if we need to remove '(' from the same line?

Comment: I changed from gsub(/{|}/,"",$i) to gsub(/{|}|)/,"",$i) and let me know if this helps.

Comment: you need to change the sample Input_file then in your post because I simply added {1)} and it removed { ) and } from it.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly just to keep the perl skills slightly honed (every 6 months or so you need to do something in perl!)

```
perl -F, -lane '$,=","; $F[$_ - 1]=~s/[{}]//g foreach(2,4,5,7); print @F;' input-file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," 'BEGIN { split("2,4,5,7", F, ","); } { for(N in F) {gsub(/[}{]/,"", $(F[N]))} }1'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.